# Подключение чанка в MODX

Tags: modx

Хочу поменять отдельный пункт меню:

```
[[!pdoMenu?
    &parents      = `0`
    &level        = `2`
    &outerClass   = `nav navbar-nav`
    &displayStart = `0`
    &tplInner     = `@INLINE <ul class="dropdown-menu">[[+wrapper]]</ul>`
    &tplParentRow = `@INLINE <li class="dropdown"><a href="[[+link]]" class="dropdown-toggle" >[[+menutitle]] <span class="caret"></span></a> [[+wrapper]]</li>`
    &tpl          = `@INLINE <li class="dropdown"><a href="[[+link]]" class="dropdown-toggle" >[[$star]][[+menutitle]] <span class="caret"></span></a> [[+wrapper]]</li>`
]]
```

Kак подключить созданный чанк `[[$star]]`, чтобы получить результат?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста подробнее, какого результата вы хотите добиться? Приведенный Вами пример работоспособен, чанк подключается, в самом чанке `star` вы можете использовать плейсхолдеры, например `[[+id]]` для вывода различного содержимого в зависимости от id документа

Comment: Спасибо решил сам